# how can I retrieve data from single table using group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have single table where I have accepted images, rejected images, and changed images in single column with action  column having action 2 accepted images, action 3 -rejected images , action 4- change images. I am able to run on "Accepted Images" but I want a different column for rejected images also. but not able to get that.  I am new to mysql please help me.  how can I get different column for rejected images

```
select  message,  date(datetime) as dateonly ,count(message)
from customer_1.audit_trail where message in ('Accepted Images') 
group by dateonly  order by dateonly asc limit 100;


 message,      dateonly, count(message)
"Accepted Images",2007-08-07,  79
"Accepted Images",2007-08-08,52
```

Comment: Could yu please clearify your question a little bit? What is the definition of the table? What are the possible values of the columns and what should be the outcome?

Comment: Sound like you need a union query. Try the sql manual.

Comment: id,user_id,location_id,plate,action,message,datetime
18,1,1,KR54SWJ,2,"Accepted Images","2007-08-07 14:17:41"
17,1,1,EJ03YXL,2,"Accepted Images","2007-08-07 14:17:30"
16,1,1,K244MSB,2,"Accepted Images","2007-08-07 14:17:24"
8,1,1,EN02WRL,2,"Accepted Images","2007-08-07 14:06:25"

Comment: sorry not able to edit properly , i need to know how many accepted Images,rejected images  on particular day

Comment: `message               message,          dateonly,    count(message) cou`
"Rejected Images "  "Accepted Images",  2007-08-07,  79  82
 Rejected Images"   "Accepted Images",  2007-08-08,   52  56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above query is wrong. You might have never get message column output because in your group by column you have only dateonly.

```
select  date(`datetime`) as dateonly ,
count(case when message= 'Accepted Images' then 1 else 0 end ) as accepted_image_count,
count(case when message= 'Rejected Images' then 1 else 0 end ) as  rejected_image_count
from customer_1.audit_trail where message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images') 
group by dateonly  order by dateonly asc limit 100;
```

Comment: thanks krishna for speedy reply but i tried this before i get the same result for  accepted and rejecetd with 2 different columns when i use this line where message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images')

Comment: where clause is not important here. the count block is more important here you use cases. If response does not change, then try sum instead of count in my query. and please let me know if you are successful

Comment: Hi krishna , I agree with you your query was right and I get the output only for accepted images only but can you tell me how can i get the rejected images in the same table.

Comment: don't you get any output in  rejected_image_count column? please check if 'Rejected Images' is correctly spelled as per your table data

Comment: If I change the statement i get the result for rejected images  but accepted images is null ..WHERE message in ('Rejected Images')  Iam just trying to get accepted images and rejected images there is something i am missing ..

Comment: HI krishna , can you tell me how can i differentiate 2 different values in single column using select statment

Comment: you can use case when in your select. can you give some data you get after changing to my query using select  date(`datetime`) as dateonly ,
sum(case when message= 'Accepted Images' then 1 else 0 end ) as accepted_image_count,
sum(case when message= 'Rejected Images' then 1 else 0 end ) as  rejected_image_count
from customer_1.audit_trail where message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images') 
group by dateonly  order by dateonly asc limit 100;

Comment: `message,dateonly,CNT_Accepted,CNT_Rejected`
`"Accepted Images",2007-08-07,79,0`
`"Rejected Images",2007-08-07,0,10`
`"Accepted Images",2007-08-08,52,0`
"Rejected Images",2007-08-13,0,1
`"Accepted Images",2007-08-14,43,0`
`"Rejected Images",2007-08-14,0,6`

Comment: In my query, I have not put message column. This is the cause of your problem. Just remove it from select list and remove it from group by list.

Comment: Thanks a lot krishna it worked brillant you are star..... I have one more query how can i get the datetime for a week and get the total..for that week.

Comment: Use week() function to get the week id and make a group by function on basis of week(`datetime`). For further details refer http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

Comment: Hi krishna i have a query  again I would like to add changed ti images in the above query like { sum(CASE message like 'Changed  to' then 1 else 0 end) as Changed to }

Comment: but where as i have 'Changed  to L785NOO' in original table how can  I retrieve data  which have 'change to' in the database.

Comment: use like operator instead of = . Try case when message like '%Changed to%'

Comment: krishna, when i tried that I am getting an error at then ..sum(CASE message like '%Changed  to%'      then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG

Comment: done when was missing.. but nothing has been returned in that columnb all zeroes... why is that ..

Comment: how should i add it in statement  where message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images','Changed to') or where message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images','%changed to%') which one is correct.

Comment: how to like and in operators in mysql.

Comment: hi krishna , how can i use datetimepickers  on this query .. {   MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(String.Format(
    "SELECT   datetime ," +
    "Sum((CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end)) as AcceptedIMG, " +
    "Sum((CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end)) as RejectedIMG, " +
    "Sum((CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end)) as ChangeIMG " +
    "FROM customer_1.audit_trail " +
    "where DATE(datetime)>= '{0}' and  DATE(datetime)<='{1}'",

    start.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    end.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "GROUP BY (datetime)"), conn);
}

Comment: r u using Java? just replace your value of datetimepickers in the required string replacement index

Comment: oh thanks  you are back .. no c# i replaced it but i get values in single  row like  04/07/2013 94152 25476 97454 buit i want it in a date wise .

Comment: change DATE(datetime)<='{1}' to  DATE(datetime)<=DATE('{1}')

Comment: 04/07/2013 94152 25476 97454 same result no change

Comment: there is a problem in your datepicker value. try to use substring to get only the date value from date picker

Comment: use substring to get only the date value from your datepicker. Problem is in your supplied parameters not in the query perhaps

Comment: it works fine if i just select from particular range  without sum but if i sum then it sums and displays in one row.  i think i am doing in placing my datetimepickers in the query.

Comment: can you give a sample data how your `datetime` field is saved. if it has time in it, and you do not want to group by time with date then just convert it to GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`) or use DATE_FORMAT( `datetime , '%Y-%m-%d' ) everywhere where you use `datetime` field

Comment: use DATE() in all your date type fields, including column names and your supplied fields

Comment: it still the same result only one row with sum in the colmns

Comment: `SELECT datetime  as date," + 
                    "Sum((CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end)) as AcceptedIMG, " +
                    "Sum((CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end)) as RejectedIMG, " + 
                    "Sum((CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end)) as ChangeIMG " + 
                    "FROM customer_1.audit_trail " +
                    "where DATE(datetime)>= '{0}' and  DATE(datetime)<=DATE('{1}') ", 
                    start.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "GROUP BY (date)"), conn);`

Comment: SELECT DATE(datetime) as date," + "Sum((CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end)) as AcceptedIMG, " + "Sum((CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end)) as RejectedIMG, " + "Sum((CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end)) as ChangeIMG " + "FROM customer_1.audit_trail " + "where DATE(datetime)>= DATE('{0}') and DATE(datetime)<=DATE('{1}') ", start.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "GROUP BY date(datetime)"), conn);

Comment: still it displays only single row 01/07/2013 105090 27863 107083

Comment: still the 02/07/2013 94310 25104 95341

Comment: put a sample data of your table, then your requirement and your updated query in another question in stackoverflow.I am unable to get what is your requiment and where is your problem in the new problem

Comment: I know its frustating but somehow tried this  got the result for the month and its working fine it works only for month. its not picking up the end datetime picker. it picks up only start date time picker.

Comment: `MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT DATE(datetime) as date," +  "Sum((CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end)) as AcceptedIMG, " + "Sum((CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end)) as RejectedIMG, " + 
                    "Sum((CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end)) as ChangeIMG "
                    + "FROM customer_1.audit_trail " + "where DATE(datetime)>= DATE('{0}') and DATE(datetime)<=DATE('{1}') GROUP BY day(datetime) ORDER BY  (datetime) asc   ", 
                    start.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), conn);`

Comment: GROUP BY day(datetime) --  01/05/2013 8413 2309 8100                                                    02/05/2013 7772 1467 6944
                         03/05/2013 9407 1662 9882
                          04/05/2013 14928 3236 14272

Comment: so its not picking the datetime picker2 (ie end date)

Comment: instead of writing >= and <= why do not try between ..and operator

Comment: thanks Sahoo atlast  I finally end up  completing  my project somehow.....thanks a lot for your help......

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be in a seperate column (which is not really clear from your description) then you can do this:

```
select  message,  date(datetime) as dateonly, count(message)
from customer_1.audit_trail 
group by message, dateonly  
order by dateonly asc limit 100;
```

otherwise you'll have to pivot the message column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  message,  date(datetime) as dateonly ,
sum(CASE message when 'Accepted Images' then 1 else 0 end) as CNT_Accepted,
sum(CASE message when 'Rejected Images' then 1 else 0 end) as CNT_Rejected
FROM customer_1.audit_trail 
WHERE message in ('Accepted Images') 
GROUP BY dateonly, message
ORDER BY dateonly asc limit 100;
```

This is one way.

Answer (score 0):

just try something like this.
make your sql table into 3 columns (image_id,action,date)

then update the action and date columns according to image id or insert to the table;
ex sql
update yourTable set action='Accepted Images',date='2013-01-01' where image_id='1';
insert into yourTable values('1','Accepted Images',2013-01-01);

then you can retrieve data according to the action status,
ex sql
select image_id,date, from yourTable where action='Accepted Images' group by date order by date asc limit 100;

if there is any additional columns needed you can manage it as your requirement.Try give the clear idea of your question next time.

Comment: hi user, thanks for the reply my table is just like what you have said but I need my output where can I get  accepted images and rejected images on single table in this line I can retrieve only one action "here action='Accepted Images' group by date"

Answer (score 0):

Create different queries for accepted and rejected. Then UNION both.